# Python package basics

Tags: python, package

I have a python file named as `test1.py`.
This file contains few `classes` and a few `functions`.

I intend to package this and distribute so that others can use it via the `pip install` command.
From other posts, I understood how we build a package.

**Q:** When the package is imported in the end user's code, using the `import <mypackage>` command,

**1.** can the functions be called directly by simply writing the function name?

**2.** methods which are part of the class, are ideally called by `objectname.methodname`, how will they be called now?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you import the package. If you import the package as

```
import test1
```

you will have to call all the classes and functions with `test1.function()`. The class methods like `test1.objectname.methodname()`

If you use

```
from test1 import *
```

you can just use the function names, but your namespace is being polluted with all the function names.

You can also import only specific functions or classes using

```
from test1 import function1, function2, class1, class2
```

To call them with just their respective name.

And lastly you can use `import test1 as t1` to make it a bit shorter, calling functions can then be done using `t1.function1()`

Answer (score 0):

functions will be appended to the package name. For example:

```
import numpy
# Calling the square root function from numpy
val = 4
newVal = numpy.sqrt(val)

# You can also do this, but it is not recommended as it pollutes your name space 
from numpy import sqrt

# Now I can call sqrt directly
val = 4
newVal = sqrt(val)
```

Class methods work similarly.